# Define XmlSchemaSet for Array of string

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create an `XmlSchemaSet` for this object:

```cs
public class ChartData
{
    public string[] SeriesNames;
     //enum
    public ChartDataType CategoryDataType;
    public int CategoryFormatCode;
    public string[] CategoryNames;

    public double[][] Values;
}
```

I tried this definition for `seriesNames` but it did not work giving me the error message:

> The `'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:complexType'` element is not supported in this context.

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault='unqualified' elementFormDefault='qualified' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
  <xs:element name='Chart'>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name='SeriesNames'>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute maxOccurs='unbounded'  type='xs:string'/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name='Values' type='xs:string' use='required' />
      <xs:attribute name='CategoryDataType' type='xs:string' use='optional' />  
      <xs:attribute name='CategoryFormatCode' type='xs:string' use='optional' />
      <xs:attribute name='CategoryNames' type='xs:string' use='required' />
      <xs:attribute name='Optional' type='xs:boolean' use='optional' />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I use the definition:

```xml
<xs:attribute name='SeriesNames' type='xs:string' use='required' />
```

when I use `XPathEvaluate` it doesn't read the string array

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault='unqualified' elementFormDefault='qualified' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
  <xs:element name='Chart'>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name='SeriesNames' type='xs:string' minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name='CategoryDataType' type='xs:string' use='optional' />  
      <xs:attribute name='CategoryFormatCode' type='xs:string' use='optional' />
      <xs:attribute name='CategoryNames' type='xs:string' use='required' />
      <xs:attribute name='Optional' type='xs:boolean' use='optional' />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jdweng for your reply but when I execute the definition I get the error : 
Schema Validation Error: The 'SeriesNames' attribute is not declared.

The code I execute is the following:

```
var XsdMarkup = @"<xs:schema attributeFormDefault='unqualified' elementFormDefault='qualified' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
                               <xs:element name='Chart'>
                                <xs:complexType>
                                         <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name='SeriesNames' type='xs:string' minOccurs="0" maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
  </xs:sequence>
                                   <xs:attribute name='Values' type='xs:string' use='required' />
                                   <xs:attribute name='CategoryDataType' type='xs:string' use='optional' /> 
                                   <xs:attribute name='CategoryFormatCode' type='xs:string' use='optional' />   
                                   <xs:attribute name='CategoryNames' type='xs:string' use='required' />    
                                  <xs:attribute name='Optional' type='xs:boolean' use='optional' />                                                                                                
                                </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                            </xs:schema>";
XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XsdMarkup));
```